# Windows Server 2012R2 - Access to folder denied for admin

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, tomcat8, permission-denied, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a folder on Windows Server 2012 that I want to delete. However, even when I try it in PowerShell or cmd.exe as admin, I'm not allowed to delete or view it. I also tried changing permissions with `icals` as admin, but was also denied.

The error message when I try to delete it looks like this.

> rmdir : Access to the path 'C:\Tomcat8.0\webapps\geoserver\data\coverages' is denied.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> rmdir .\data
>
> CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Tomcat8.0\webapps\geoserver\data:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

I read that this can be caused by a bug in UAC (User Account Control), so I set it to `Never notify`, but that didn't change it either.

**Background** (I'm not sure if this caused the problem): The folder was created by deploying geoserver on Tomcat 8 and trying to manually delete it. The entire folder structure was deleted except for this one folder.

**Edit:** Maybe it's also worth mentioning that it doesn't matter whether Tomcat is running or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to delete it now. The folder seemed to be locked by the explorer process somehow.

Solution: Open cmd as administrator, then stop the explorer task, delete the folder and start a new instance of explorer.exe.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution:
Open cmd as administrator, then stop the explorer task,
or open the task manger and end task windows explorer
delete the folder and
start a new instance of explorer.exe from task manger (explorer).
This worked for me.